# SQL - instead of INSERT and temporary variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, ssms

i make this trigger for inserting new PersonID to customers table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insert_PersonID]  ON  [dbo].[CustomersTB]

instead of INSERT 
as

BEGIN
    declare @PersonID int;
    select @PersonID = (select PersonID from inserted)

    if  (@PersonID<=999999999) and
        (not EXISTS (Select PersonID From [dbo].[CustomersTB] where @PersonID = [dbo].[CustomersTB].PersonID))
    begin
        .
        .   
    end 
END
```

when insert manually one PersonID it work, but when tring to insert from other tables i get this error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

pointed to the line:

> select @PersonID = (select PersonID from inserted)

can't understand what and how to change it

Comment: Of course it doesn't work.  Your code is assuming that `inserted` has only one row.  Treat it like a table and rewrite the query.

Comment: `inserted` has **every** row that was inserted, not just one of them. A trigger fires **once per DML statement** *not* once per row effected by a DML statement. If your `INSERT` statement inserts 1,000 rows, then your trigger `tr_insert_PersonID` will fire once with the information for all of those rows contained within `inserted`, not 1,000 times for each row.

Comment: `select @PersonID = (select PersonID from inserted)` <-- this fetch **all** `PersonID` from the table `inserted`

Comment: Another red flag unrelated to your current problem is `ISNUMERIC`. It answers a question you probably don't want to ask. Or are e.g. `123456D78` and `$0,,,,,,,` valid PersonIDs in your world?

Comment: thanks all! how do i change it so i could insert PersonID from other tables and it check each row?

Comment: any options? how to check every row (like when using WHERE clause)

Answer (score 3):

Along with everything that was written in the comments up to now (the last comment currently is Damien's about the `ISNUMERIC` answering the question you don't want to ask), 
It seems like you are using the `instead of` trigger for validation - and in that case, you've picked the wrong tool for the job.

Except in very specific cases, validation should be achieved using constraints.

In your case, you should first make sure you are using the proper data type for `PersonId`.

If you want it numeric, use a numeric data type. If you want it to be an integer, use `int` (or in case of an extremely large integer, `bigint`).

If you want it to be unique, add a [unique index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) or [unique constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) to it, or consider if it should be the [primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#PKeys) of the table (which is unique by definition).

If you want it to be a number with at least 9 digits, add a [check constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) that will reject any value under `100,000,000`.

Comment: thanks a lot! in this case i'm using INT, but i will do it to other variables and columns with different types. i will handle each type differently..